# custom camera zoom crashes (reboots) Samsung mobile

Tags: android, pinchzoom

//custom camera zoom crashes (reboots) Samsung mobile android

```
void onZoom1() {
    if (mStreamer == null || mVideoCaptureState != Streamer.CAPTURE_STATE.STARTED) {
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Set Camera.Parameters manually");
    parameters = mStreamerGL.getCameraParameters();
    if (parameters != null) {
        if (parameters.isZoomSupported()) {
            parameters.setZoom((int) mScaleFactor);
        }
        mStreamerGL.setCameraParameters(parameters);
    }
}
```

//This is how I implement pinch zoom

```
public void onZoom2() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return;
    }
    if (mStreamer == null || mVideoCaptureState != Streamer.CAPTURE_STATE.STARTED) {
        return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Set Camera2 CaptureRequest manually");
    final String cameraId = mStreamerGL.getActiveCameraId();
    final android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager cameraManager = (android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CaptureRequest.Builder builder = mStreamerGL.createCaptureRequest();
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        if (builder == null || characteristics == null) {
            return;
        }


        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

        if (mMaxZoom > 1.0f) {


            Rect sensor = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
            int sensorCenterX = sensor.width() / 2;
            int sensorCenterY = sensor.height() / 2;
            int deltaX = (int) (0.5f * sensor.width() / mScaleFactor);
            int deltaY = (int) (0.5f * sensor.height() / mScaleFactor);

            Rect zoomRect = new Rect(
                    sensorCenterX - deltaX,
                    sensorCenterY - deltaY,
                    sensorCenterX + deltaX,
                    sensorCenterY + deltaY);

            builder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomRect);
        }
        mStreamerGL.setRepeatingRequest(builder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

//My ScaleListener

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
        if (mMaxZoom < 0) {
            findMaxZoom();
        }
        mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, mMaxZoom));
        Log.d(TAG, "Max zoom=" + mMaxZoom + " zoom=" + (int) mScaleFactor);
        if (mUseCamera2) {
            onZoom2();
        } else {
            onZoom1();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

//The above code works on all the mobile devices except Samsung mobile. The Samsung mobile is getting frozen and then rebooted while I try to zoom.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find the solution?